# How to decode buffer in Netty with unknown length?

Tags: java, sockets, protocols, netty

I've searched for many examples in Netty project and they seem simple and great. However, decoders have one thing in common: they read some header first and then they know in advance how many bytes to read.

I have to implement more complex protocol. It's a proprietary binary protocol construced like this:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------+
| header | msg_count | msg_type_1 | msg_1 | msg_type_n | msg_n | msg_count |
+--------+-----------+------------+-------+------------+-------+-----------+
 11 bytes    1 byte      1 byte     bytes     1 byte     bytes     1 byte
```

Header contains serial number. Then there is message count and n messages. These messages varies in length. At the end of transmission there is message count reprised again and it's a sign of a completed transmission.

Messages can have different types. Some types are fixed width, but some types varies, e. g.:

- msg type 0x01: fixed width of 4 bytes
- msg type 0x02: first byte - message length of m, then m bytes

I don't have a clue how to implement Netty decoder for such protocol. Main problem here is that there is no clear sign of an end until I actually parse the whole buffer - messages are parsed fine and message count is reprised at the end.

Is there any mechanism in Netty that can help me solve this case?

Comment: how do you know when a message ends and a new message starts?

Comment: @jtahlborn after reprised msg_count at the end, there can be another header incoming right away. There is no delimiter.

Comment: no, how do you know the boundary between msg_1 and msg_type_n?

Comment: @jtahlborn I've improved my post with message types and lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you should be able to implement a [ReplayingDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html).  Maybe not the most efficient implementation, but probably the simplest.